# iOS swift vpn connecting immediately disconnected

Tags: ios, swift, networking, vpn, openvpn

I have used three methods but all get the same result

1.only use Network Extension to connect the VPN

2.use OpenAdapter Demo
https://github.com/ss-abramchuk/OpenVPNAdapter

3.use tunnelKit Demo
https://github.com/passepartoutvpn/tunnelkit/issues

and I had check my configuration many times ,the tunnel bundle id is correct

I just did a few steps

clone the project
2.change the App Groups and Keychain Sharing group
App IDs and Tunnel extension id and use my provisioning profile (demo-iOS,Tunnel-iOS,WireGuardTunnel-iOS)
3.modify the Configuration
4.run the project
5.set the IP address and username password
6.press connect button

and the console log always print

17:19:27 DEBUG NetworkExtensionVPN.notifyReinstall():264 - VPN did reinstall (com.bw.business.ap02-dev.Tunnel): isEnabled=true
VPNStatusDidChange: connecting
17:19:27 DEBUG NetworkExtensionVPN.notifyStatus():278 - VPN status did change (com.bw.business.ap02-dev.Tunnel): isEnabled=true, status=2
VPNStatusDidChange: disconnecting
17:19:28 DEBUG NetworkExtensionVPN.notifyStatus():278 - VPN status did change (com.bw.business.ap02-dev.Tunnel): isEnabled=true, status=5
VPNStatusDidChange: disconnected

even other methods always
connecting => disconnecting = disconnected

please help me

Answer (score 2):

I faced with the similar issue and I've found that tunnel ID must match the bundle ID of your network extension

Example:
if extension bundle ID is `"com.company.vpn-tunnel"`
then

```
let protocolConfiguration = NETunnelProviderProtocol()
protocolConfiguration.providerBundleIdentifier = "com.company.vpn-tunnel"
protocolConfiguration.serverAddress = ...
```

For TunnelKit:

```
let vpn: NetworkExtensionVPN = NetworkExtensionVPN()
...
try await vpn.reconnect("com.company.vpn-tunnel", configuration: ...)
```

Comment: I've tried this recently and am still having the same issue